# Battery Capacity Problem in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: power-management, laptop, hp, battery

I have a one month old HP Notebook 15 laptop and I installed Ubuntu 18.10 with all updates and upgrades and everything is working fine but my only concern is the continuous decrease
of the capacity of the battery every time I use my laptop.

I'm doing partial discharge regularly
so when the battery indicator says 40% remaining, I power off the laptop, wait for a few hours
and then recharge it to 100% but every time I turn on my laptop and open "Power Statistics" in Ubuntu, I find a .2 to .5 percent decrease in battery capacity.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to wait until the battery percentage indicator reaches 30% or 20% before I recharge the battery?
Is it possible that Ubuntu is showing incorrect or inaccurate battery capacity?